# Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial chapter 12 — undefined method `users'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on Michal Hartl's tutorial and I'm getting error after first test.

```
E

Error:
RelationshipTest#test_should_be_valid:
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<RelationshipTest:0x00007feb7da11100>
    test/models/relationship_test.rb:6:in `setup'


bin/rails test test/models/relationship_test.rb:10

E

Error:
RelationshipTest#test_should_require_a_followed_id:
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<RelationshipTest:0x00007feb7dadf2a8>
    test/models/relationship_test.rb:6:in `setup'


bin/rails test test/models/relationship_test.rb:19

E

Error:
RelationshipTest#test_should_require_a_follower_id:
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<RelationshipTest:0x00007feb7e8d04e8>
    test/models/relationship_test.rb:6:in `setup'


bin/rails test test/models/relationship_test.rb:14
```

Here is my relationship_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class RelationshipTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @relationship = Relationship.new(follower_id: users(:michael).id,
                                    followed_id: users(:archer).id)
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @relationship.valid?
  end

  test "should require a follower_id" do
    @relationship.follower_id = nil
    assert_not @relationship.valid?
  end

  test "should require a followed_id" do
    @relationship.followed_id = nil
    assert_not @relationship.valid?
  end
end
```

I'm really confused by error, so any help would be appreciated. I've tried to search other answers, but couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the fixtures, at least for users?

Comment: @SebastianPalma thank you, I just added it

Comment: @SebastianPalma no, I'm not sure, how would I check it?

Comment: Have you defined user fixtuers in test/fixtures/users.yml? If so, does your `test_helper.rb` have a line `fixtures :all` in the body of the `ActiveSupport::TestCase` class?

Comment: If you're missing a `test/fixtures/users.yml` file this might not know how to load your dummy users.

Comment: @edwardmp I do not have users.yml at all because it was not listed in the instructions. relationships.yml is empty, so what should I put there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create and put some fixtures in `test/fixtures/users.yml`.

Example (you probably need to adapt it to your own database design):

```
michael:
  email: "user_1@example.com"
  uid: "user_1@example.com"
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>
```

This fixture would now be accesible in your test as `users(:michael)`.
Check the [Rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures) for more info.